# Android: Should I pass in serializable or recreate the object from Bundle?

Tags: java, android, serialization, bundle

So I have a Calendar obj which implements serializable by default and I want to pass it in a bundle so the value of it is saved on screen rotation.

Should I pass it as a serializable or extract the values and recreate the obj for efficiency?

```
bundle.putSerializable("key", calendar);
```

or

```
bundle.putInt("dayKey", calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
bundle.putInt("monthKey", calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH));
bundle.putInt("yearKey", calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
```

Comment: i will go with putSerializable. i dont know about the efficency, but its easier to implement and to read rather than explode the object into pieces. What if a serializable object have more than 10 attribut

Comment: I would go with the simplest and least error prone possibility: `bundle.putInt("time", calendar.getTime().getTime());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Serializable` is not recommended in `Android`; use `Parcelable` instead.

I would guess it depends on the size of the `Object` and how cumbersome it is to recreate manually.

Answer (score 1):

Go with `Parcelable` over `Serializable`.  If performance matters, `Parcelable` could be around 10x faster (http://www.developerphil.com/parcelable-vs-serializable/)

Additionally, you can use https://github.com/johncarl81/parceler to avoid generating (and maintaining!) all the boilerplate code that would otherwise exist.

```
@Parcel
public class Person {
  ...
}

Parcelable parcelable = Parcels.wrap(new Person(..));
Person = Parcels.unwrap(parcelable);
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, while `Parcelable` is definitely the preferred serialization method, I think for this case you're fine just putting it as a `Serializable` extra. Considering the amount of work that is done recreating the `Activity`, I think the expense of serializing a `Calendar` instance would be negligible.

If nothing else, it makes your code more maintainable and succinct.

Answer (score 0):

- onSaveInstanceState method is used for store Activity's state. and it called when activity you **rotate the screen** or **press home button** or open new **activity from notification bar**.
- It called after onPause() method.
- You can save your custom Object or any primitive data type i.e. called Activities's states as

  ```
  @Override
  protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
      super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);        
      outState.putSerializable(KEY_CALENDAR, cal);        
  }
  ```
- onRestoreInstanceState() method is used for restore your Activities's states.
- It called after the onStart() method
- You can Activities's state restore like

  ```
  @Override
  protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);       
      cal = (Calendar) savedInstanceState.getSerializable(KEY_CALENDAR);
  }
  ```

  Here you can use serializable for save Activities's state.
- You can also use onCreate() method for restore your saved state because bundle is same deliver in both method onCreate(), onRestoreInstanceState() like

  ```
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

      if(savedInstanceState != null) {
          cal = (Calendar) savedInstanceState.getSerializable(KEY_CALENDAR);
      } else {
          cal = Calendar.getInstance();
          cal.setTime(new Date());    
      }
  }
  ```